# Android X86 on vmware, Google Play requires wifi

Tags: android, x86, vmware, google-play, emulation

I installed Android X86 4.0 RC2 (eeepc edition) on a vmware machine (I prefer VMware because it is really faster than Android Virtual Device). I enabled ethernet with the terminal, and Internet and Maps are running pefectly.

But, when I open Google Play, (I need this service, not only for install apps), it asks for an  account and requires the wifi connection to complete the operation. Obviusly, VMware don't emulate wifi network.

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The account information is needed for obvious reasons. With regards to wireless you could try writing a kernel module that fakes it. My personal advice is to use a physical device, as I've always found emulation to be lacking

Comment: Thanks for help. Unluckily, I have not a physical laptop available for testing. How I could try to write a fake wireless kernel module?

Comment: An Android x86 fork "AndroVM" (Official site no longer exist, mirror: http://mirror1.jarfil.net/androvm.org/Download/) seems contain some hacks to fake wifi status so apps require Wifi correctly work on Ethernet. It does work on VMWare, though you don't get any sound emulation. (The sequel "Genymotion" is VirtualBox only)